# Check for multiple UTF-8 codes when a specific UTF-8 code is requested

Tags: php, d3.js, utf-8, jquery-select2, arabic

I am using Select2 to search for Arabic names in PHP to render in D3JS tree. I want to be able to treat several UTF-8 codes same as the one selected by the user.

my Psudo code of what I am trying to achieve is:

If (first letter == U+0627) then search for first letter (U+0627 && U+0622 && U+0623 && U+0625)

That is if the user types the Arabic letter "ا"   then search also for letters "آ"   and "أ" and "إ" as well, as the first letter of the string.

The code included is for the custom matcher, in which I want to be able to have the above functionality.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      // initializing the selectpicker
        $('.selectpicker').select2({
            placeholder: "Select",
            matcher: function(params, data) {
                          return matchStart(params, data);
                      }
          });
          // Script for select2 filter
          function matchStart(params, data) {
              params.term = params.term || '';
              if (data.text.toUpperCase().indexOf(params.term.toUpperCase()) == 0) {
                  return data;
              }
              return false;
          }
```

Comment: Note: JavaScript doesn't have anything to do with UTF-8. Strings are counted sequences of UTF-16 code units. Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are character encodings for the Unicode character set. The U+  notation you've used—very appropriately—is for discussion of Unicode codepoints. In JavaScript, U+0627 would be by UTF-16 code units or character literal or Unicode codepoint escape ("\u0627" or "ا" or "\u{0627}").

Comment: Thank you Tom for the clarification.  I would appreciate a sample code as I have mentioned in the example code.